# Need to parse the JSON ARRAYS that are inside the JSON Object in JAVA

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am trying to parse the JSON data which is present in datas.json.I need to parse the Exclusion datas using Beans/POJO classes.The JSON data is as follows:
    `"ExclusionList" : {
                  "serviceLevel" : ["sl1","sl2","sl3"],
                  "item" : ["ABC","XYZ"]                                                                 }  }`

I've created POJO classes for the ExclusionList but unable to get and print in the console of ECLIPSE IDE.Mypojo class:

```
List<String> serviceLevel;
List<String> item;
//with gettter and setters.
```

My main class is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
            throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, ParseException, JSONException {
    File jsonFile = new File("C:\\Users\\sameepra\\Videos\\datas.json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
    ExclusionList exclusionlist=mapper.readValue(jsonFile,ExclusionList.class);
    List<String> excllist=exclusionlist.getServiceLevel();
    for (int i = 0; i < excllist.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(excllist.get(i));
    }
}
```

Getting error as *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*

Comment: have you initialized `List<String> excllist` ??

Comment: Its already inititalized on that provided line as String:

Comment: String type List*

Comment: post your console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need to wrap your pojo class in another containing an ExclusionList property.
Try this. The examples below uses lombok for getters , setters and default constructor.


import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ExclusionListWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("ExclusionList")
    private ExclusionList exclusionList;

    @Data
    class ExclusionList {
        List<String>    serviceLevel;
        List<String>    item;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data = "{\"ExclusionList\" : {\"serviceLevel\" : [\"sl1\",\"sl2\",\"sl3\"], \"item\" : [\"ABC\",\"XYZ\"]}}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        ExclusionListWrapper exclusionlistWrapper = mapper.readValue(data, ExclusionListWrapper.class);
        List<String> excllist = exclusionlistWrapper.getExclusionList().getServiceLevel();
        for (int i = 0; i < excllist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(excllist.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```